# Boot Visual changed on me

Tags: boot, shutdown

I used to get the default boot and shut down visuals. For instance The Ubuntu logo with purple background when I had dual boot with windows. When I wiped my windows completely I chose to encrypt my files automatically and have a boot password. For a while it stayed the same way and the boot password was just entered in a black box. But then it changed on me and its all in wording and says Enter Paraphrase: The boot/shutdown recently changed and I'm not sure what caused it. It just cycles through text and checks now instead of just having the regular loading screens. The computer also started running a little slower after this change, and I'm not sure what I did to mess it up. Someone please help =(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to debug the problem. I switched back to the open source video driver and things seem to be running normal again. (Normal being what I prefer in this situation) I'm going to leave this open for a few more days to see if I get any comments regarding the situation or other solutions to make boot/shutdown "look" smoother instead of worded commands. I want to keep the Ubuntu loading screen, like it hehe.